# checkstyle module name ConstantName vs ConstantNameCheck

Tags: checkstyle

I have a question to ask regarding checkstyle.
It seems that the checkstyle api accepts both module name,
ConstantName and ConstantNameCheck (ConstantName with Check concatenated) for the configuration file, checkstyle.xml.

I would like to ask why is there a double standard here even though documentations on http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/ only promotes ConstantName module and what is the difference between using either of them? Will either one of them gets deprecated in future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, the [ConstantName](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#ConstantName) check is implemented by a Java class called
`com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.ConstantNameCheck`.

You could actually refer to the module in *checkstyle.xml* by this so-called "fully qualified" name. The other notations are shorthand offered by Checkstyle for convenience. `ConstantNameCheck` is the simple name of the implementing Java class, and `ConstantName` is still shorter. Checkstyle will try all three variants when looking for the module in your *checkstyle.xml*. So, there is no difference between these notations.

The recommended way is to use the most concise form, `ConstantName`, but as far as I know, none of the other forms is going to get deprecated any time soon.